# How to call a Cloud Function from Google Apps Script with Authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a test with the "Hello World" Cloud Function code sample, but when I call it I get 401 HTTP error even I've already added the Invoker role to the requester user email. Is there anything else that I need to do on the request to run this function?

I'm trying to do the GET like this in Google Scripts:

```
function test(){
   var url = 'https:******************/HelloWorld';
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
   Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

And the Python "Hello World" Cloud Function code sample is:

```
def hello_world(request):
"""Responds to any HTTP request.
Args:
    request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
Returns:
    The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
    Response object using
    `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
"""
request_json = request.get_json()
if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
    return request.args.get('message')
elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
    return request_json['message']
else:
    return f'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you browse the Cloud Functions endpoint successfully?

`https:******************/HelloWorld`

In my case (you may try this), my URL for the HelloWorld example used the default `function-1` name, so my URL is:

`https://us-central1-dazwilkin-200204-60062279.cloudfunctions.net/function-1`

I created an Apps Script function using the above URL and it works:

```
[20-02-04 10:44:18:857 PST] Hello World!
```

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, I've tried to browse with both function name (`HelloWorld` and `function-1`) but I got 403 HTTP Error! Did you do another config to buit your function?

Comment: Cloud Functions are publicly accessible so, you should be able to use my URL in your Apps Script code to test too. I did no additional configuration and ran the Apps Script function from the editor.

Comment: If you have `gcloud` installed, you can confirm the endpoint using: `gcloud functions describe function-1 --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)"`. For `function-1` (if it exists), this will return its HTTPS endpoint

Comment: To list the functions `gcloud functions list --project=${PROJECT]`.

Comment: Sorry -- one more -- if you can't browse the Cloud Function, that's your problem.

Comment: I used the commands that you listed and I confirmed that my function is active. The endpoint is the same that I'm trying to fetch, So I didn't undertand what I can't to browse the Cloud Function.

Comment: One point here: When you deployed your function, did you uncheck the option of Don't allow no-auth invokes??

Comment: I "Allow unauthenticated invocations" so that e.g. you can call my function. If you secure the Function then you'll need to generate a Bearer Token to gain access to the function.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Comment: Hi, @DazWilkin. Thanks for your help! I saw the doc that you've pointed, but I've not found how to generate the Token. Do you have any link about this?

Comment: I've not tried it with authentication and my auth fu is weak. However, I think you may succeed by trying the Google Sign-in (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#google_sign-in) and then using `getIdentityToken` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken) in your Apps Script. When you succeed, this would make a useful tutorial!